# linux kernel and user address spaces

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In 4GB RAM system running linux, 3gb is given to user-space and 1gb to kernel, does it mean that even if kernel is using 50MB and user space is running low, user cannot use kernel space? if no, why? why cannot linux map their pages to user space?

Comment: seems you are confusing virtual space and physical space

Comment: It means 3GB of *virtual memory space* is available to each user-space process.  One user-space process could map 2GB of memory, and a second user-space process could map another (2GB - 50MB) of memory, using all available physical memory.

Comment: Damn, that's right, I was confusing those two but now new question arose: why? every process has its own VAS right? why does it limit to 3gb?

Answer (score 4):

The 3/1 separation refers to VIRTUAL memory. The virtual memory, however, is sparse. Meaning that even though there is "on paper" 1 GB, in practice a LOT less than that is used. Whenever possible, the "virtual" memory is backed by physical pages (meaning, if your virtual memory footprint is 50MB, then you're using 50 MB of physical memory), up until the point where there is no more physical memory, in which case you either A) spill over to swap or B) the system encounters a low memory condition and frees memory the hard way - by killing processes.

It gets more complicated. Virtual memory is not really used (committed) until actually used. THis means when you allcoate memory, you get an "IOU" or "promise" for memory, but the memory only gets consumed when you actually use the memory, as in write some value to it. Overall, however, you are correct in that there is segregation - at the hardware level - between kernel and user mode. In other words, of the 4GB addressable (assuming 32bit), the top 1GB, even though it is in your address space, is not accessible to you, and in practice belongs to the kernel. (The limit of 4 GB stems from 32-bit pointers - for 64 bits, it's effectively 48, which means 256TB, btw, 128TB user, 128TB kernel). Further, this 1GB of your space that is the kernel's is identical in other processes, too. So it doesnt matter which process you are in, when you "call kernel", (i.e. a system call), you end up in the top 1GB, which is shared in between all processes.

Again, the key point is that the 1GB isn't REALLY used in full. The actual memory footprint of the kernel is a lot smaller - in the tens of MB. It's jsut that theoretically, the kernel can use UP to 1GB, but that is assuming it can be backed up either by RAM or (rarely) swap. You can look at /proc/meminfo. As for the answer above, about changing 3/1 - it actually CAN be changed (in Windows it's as easy as a kernel command line option in boot.ini, in Linux it requires recompilation).

Answer (score 2):

The 3GB/1GB split in *process space* is fixed. There is no way to change it regardless of how much RAM is actually in use.